# How to run CSS animation again in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations

There are quite a few similar questions, but I haven't found a clear answer.

Sometimes, I need to run CSS animation in React again, after it's complete, under certain condition. There's usually quite complex logic behind this case, so I simplified it to show what I mean without extra complexity.

Let's say I'm having a checkbox to decide whether I want the animation to run or not:

[image: Spinner]

When checkbox is disabled, the animation stops, but it finishes its cycle if it's already going. I was wondering what is the proper way to re-run the animation (i.e. remove the class and add it again) with React. Here's my component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Spinner() {
  const [isSpinning, setIsSpinning] = useState(true);
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(true);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (isChecked) {
        setIsSpinning(true);
      }
    },
    [isChecked]
  );

  const spin = () => {
    setIsSpinning(false);

    if (isChecked) {
      // without setTimeout() it doesn't work
      window.setTimeout(() => setIsSpinning(true));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={toggleCheckbox}
      />
      <div
        className={isSpinning && 'spinning'}
        onAnimationEnd={endSpin}
      >
        Hello!
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the CSS:

```css
@keyframes spinning {
    from {
        transform: rotateX(0);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotateX(360deg);
    }
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    gap: .5em;
}

.spinning {
    animation: spinning 1s;
}
```

I'm using `window.setTimeout(fn)` to add class name again after it's removed. Otherwise, it happens in the same render cycle and it behaves like the class was always there, so animation never re-runs. It works, but isn't there another, less hacky way to add class in next render cycle in React?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";

const Test = () => {

    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

    return (
        <StyledWrapper>
            <div className="container">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={isChecked}
                    onChange={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked)}
                />
                <div
                    className={isChecked ? "spinning" : ""}
                >
                    Hello!
                </div>
            </div>
        </StyledWrapper>
    )
}

export default Test;

const StyledWrapper = styled.div`

.container {
    display: flex;
    gap: .5em;
}

.spinning {
    animation: spin 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    
    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
`;
```

You can use something like this. There is a property called animation-iteration-count in css, which can be given as infinite. And furthur manage a state where based on the checkbox click you toggle the boolean value. Now you can pass the className based on these boolean values.